# How to load latex .sty files from a subdirectory?

Tags: latex, package, xelatex

I use some .sty-files that are not part of texlive and want to have them in a subdirectory of the folder with my main.tex. I used the following line to load the package:

```
\usepackage{sty/prettythesis}
```

This works, but compiling the main.tex with xelatex and using [rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber) gives me a warning:

```
sty/prettythesis.sty: You have requested package `sty/prettythesis',
but the package provides `prettythesis'. (page 1)
```

Is there a way to prevent this warning or handle this case without having to include "sty\" in all .sty-files' \ProvidesPackage command or set the TEXINPUTS environment variable (which seems not to be possible from the main.tex itself)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe this thread here:

- [LaTeX Community • View topic - Including tex files](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1756)

talks about precisely the same thing: so it seems, the only alternatives are either using `TEXINPUTS` environment variable; or using the [import package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/import.html). (*note, there is a variant on the `import` package on [...Including tex files pg 3.](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1756&start=20#p7883)*)

A bit more about TEXINPUTS:

- [TeX Frequently Asked Questions -- “Temporary” installation of (La)TeX files](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=tempinst)
- [Setting TeX Environment Variable Paths](http://www2.lbl.gov/IT/CIS/UNIX/Software/modules/tex/paths.html)
- [Environment Variables for Running LaTeX](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/cs188/latex-examples/environment.html)
- [TeX (and Variations) for Writing Math - math.umn.edu](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/tex/) (see 'TeX Inputs')
- [Installing LaTeX packages - TeX search paths](http://www.volkerschatz.com/tex/tpacks.html#kpathsea)

Hope this helps;
Cheers!

EDIT: I hoped that one could set the TEXINPUTS path directly in the tex file (*by using `\write18` -- and note, some versions of LaTeX use `--enable-write18`, mine uses `-shell-escape` to enable `\write18`; see also [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=768)*) - but it seems it is not possible:

> "*... This isn't possible. ... The environment variable of the child process is set, but this hasn't an effect to its parent process (TeX).*" ([Re: Setting the environmental variable TEXINPUTS within latex - comp.text.tex](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2006-12/msg01539.html)).

... so, now I just call `pdflatex` in my Linux `bash` like this:

> `TEXINPUTS=.//:$TEXINPUTS pdflatex ./myfile.tex`

and then it will resolve directly `\usepackage{mypackage}` in the `myfile.tex` file - even if `mypackage.sty` is in a subdirectory, say `./subdir/mypackage.sty`.

Comment: The most portable solution would be to use a `latexmkrc` file with a subdirectory added to TEXINPUTS. See the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474915

Answer (score 9):

As you discovered, putting the package in a subdirectory (say, `./sty/prettythesis.sty` with respect to your main `.tex` file at `./`), and calling the package via

```
\usepackage{sty/prettythesis}
```

will successfully load the package, but it will produce the warning

```
sty/prettythesis.sty: You have requested package `sty/prettythesis',
but the package provides `prettythesis'. (page 1)
```

---

If all you want is to get rid of this warning, and you're OK with minor modifications in the `.sty` file, then you can simply change the package name that it reports, by changing the `\ProvidesPackage` command to

```
\ProvidesPackage{sty/prettythesis}
```

---

This can be inconvenient if you're going to be moving it around loads, but the modifications load isn't too bad either.

Even better, if what you have in there is a specific, modified version of a standard TeX package (like, say, [this patch of natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13701)), then the change in the package name clearly indicates what package it's providing, and if you reuse the file then it will (most likely) re-raise a warning to prompt you into making sure that you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in your TeX file without changing your system's environment (do not forget the trailing slash `/` with each directory):

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{../one-directory/}{../another-directory/}}
\makeatother

\documentclass{myclass} 
\usepackage{mypackage}
```

This way, though, may be not recommended for portability. As other answers mention, the "correct" way is to set the `TEXINPUTS` variable in your system environment before you call latex; in Windows it is (you can place it in a batch file):

```
set TEXINPUTS=../one-directory/;../another-directory/;%TEXINPUTS%
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

Comment: this presumably also works in overleaf, which is why it is better than the modification of the path on the unix shell.

Answer (score 5):

Simply put line below before the call to pdflatex (or latex) in your makefile or build script:

```
export TEXINPUTS=".:./sty:"
```

Then reference your package as:

```
\usepackage{prettythesis}
```

Comment: Doing this make it unable to find other packages, in my case. How to know which default directories to also add to the environment variable?

Comment: According to the official documentation, it _should_ find system packages.  ("man pdftex" in my system says so).  Aren't you missing the final colon (":")?

Comment: I have to use a double colon at the end of the export statement, otherwise it can't find my `main.tex` somehow. I'm on Mac. The complete line I used was `export TEXINPUTS=".:./pkg/::"`. I can't use the double slash because I have other tex projects in subdirectories.